# Remove white spaces from BrightScript string

Tags: brightscript

I am attempting to remove leading and trailing white spaces from my string using regex

```
regexQuote = CreateObject("roRegex", "/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/g+", "i")
regexQuote.ReplaceAll(noSpaceString)
print noSpaceString
```

**[EDIT]**

```
regexQuote = CreateObject("roRegex", "/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/g", "")
print len(noSpaceString) //this value includes leading white spaces, which I dont want
```

I also tried

```
regexQuote = CreateObject("roRegex", "/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/", "")
```

And tried

```
regexQuote = CreateObject("roRegex", "/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/", "")
```

Comment: Is there a significance to the `g+` or the `i`? My first thoughts are to remove the `i` flag since you're matching white space and not alphas and remove the `+` after the `g` unless it's some weird brightscript thing which I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Have you try with : 
/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/

Comment: @Tom tried your rec but length is still showing the white spaces

Comment: Have you ever used regexes on this platform before?  A quick look at the [docs](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifRegex) tells me you don't have to add delimiters to the regex string like you do in PHP, and you don't need the `g` modifier because the `ReplaceAll()` function does just what it says: replace all matches.

Comment: can you try that : `print len(regexQuote.ReplaceAll(noSpaceString))` I think ReplaceAll return a new string and doesn't change the original one

Comment: @AlanMoore this is my first time using regex on this platform. Will try your recs

Comment: I update my regex statement and assigned it to a new variable. This solved the problem. Thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use `trim()`

Use `trim()`, Luke! There is a string method just for the purpose:

```
BrightScript Debugger> ? len("   four   ".trim())
 4
```

Answer (score 0):

From Roku's `ifString` ops you can use `Replace` as:

```
newString = originalString.Replace(" ", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

Using help from the comment section here is the solution

```
regexQuote = CreateObject("roRegex", "^\s+|\s+$", "")
newString= regexQuote.ReplaceAll(oldString, "")
print "string length:" ; len(newString)
```