# Remove whitespace from string in brightscript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I cannot find a method to remove whitespace characters e.g. spaces from a string in  Brightscript language.  Basically is there a way of taking all of the spaces out of  a string regardless of where in the string the space occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else has had this problem it's fairly easy. I had found an answer here earlier suggesting the use of [trim()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237143/remove-white-spaces-from-brightscript-string) however there's a pretty easy function that will do the job under Roku / Brightscripts ifString ops called replace. Just use your variable name dot replace e.g.

newString = originalString.Replace(" ", "")